# How can we pass user details in oauth response in Hybris 6.7

Tags: web-services, authentication, oauth-2.0, sap-commerce-cloud

We need to pass the oauth token along with the user details for a mobile app webservice in Hybris 6.7.
Can anyone please help with the customization steps ?

Comment: I am sorry but, your question is not clear for me. "mobile app webservice" is rest service? hybris has mobileservice extension but it is not about web services. Do you want to use hybris rest services with oauth?

Comment: I have a requirement..where I need to pass the user login id in response along with oauth token to mobile app . How can we achieve this ? Do we have any OOB configuration for this ?

Comment: Please check oauth concept and hybris mobile apps sdk examples.

Answer (score 0):

Hybris uses Spring Security OAuth for the implementation of OAuth2.

And as far as I can tell, you can not easily modify how the Spring framework generates the token response, since OAuth2 is a strictly defined standard.